# Using PHP to get a file location for it to be used in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I want to get an unknown number of actual `.json` files, retrieve a few values from within the files and input them into a webpage.

My full code is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e4f4488951efbdfe3431eeabbe980d80

I cannot determine how many files/ folders there might be in my project so I'm having to use a for loop to loop through a PHP array which checks a file directory on my server and determines how many 'fields' it needs to create on the page.

Here is a screenshot of what my page looks like

[image]

On the webpage itself, there are 4 'boxes' which have the `environment` title, each of those environment boxes contain an undefined number of `features` (all of these are folder names on my server). Within each `feature` there are an underfined number of folders which are named as a `date`, each `date` has an undefined number of folders which are named as `times`, each time contains two files, the `.json` file which I want to read information from and an `.html` file which I want to provide a link to when I click the `times` (see screenshot).

At the moment, for 4 environment, 2 features each, 5 days in each feature and 12 time folders within each day, the webpage generates approximately 90,000 lines of code which I believe is not the best way forward as it takes around ~11s to load the page itself.

Is there a more efficient way of calling each `.json` file, retrieving the data and inserting it into the webpage? If so, please would someone provide me with an example as to how to do it?

Edit - if the code is difficult to follow:

The `folderStructure` 6 dimensional array stores values as follows:

`$folderStructure[$e][$f][$d][$t][][]`
`$e` -> Environment Name 
`$f` -> Feature Name 
`$d` -> Date 
`$t` -> Time 
`Position 5` -> Name of `.json` file 
`Position 6` -> Name of `.html` file

Example of how I use the 6D array to retrieve folder & file names: 
`$folderStructure[0][0][0][0][0][0]` = production
`$folderStructure[0][1][0][0][0][0]` = 2-D Compare
`$folderStructure[0][1][1][0][0][0]` = 2016-08-24
`$folderStructure[0][1][1][1][0][0]` = 12.01.47
`$folderStructure[0][1][1][1][1][0]` = `production2-dcompare2016-08-2412-01-47.json`
`$folderStructure[0][1][1][1][1][1]` = `production2-dcompare2016-08-2412-01-47.html`

And I'm using a for loop for each of those array positions to iterate through the values.

Comment: Have you considered using a database?

Comment: @SamDufel Entirely possible however, I don't particularly want to have 1000's of irrelevant rows after a 28 day period when the days will be deleted from the server :\ (Probably should've mentioned that in the question, my mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how fresh the results should be, you can:

1 Create a cron job to cache the php output each hour.

2 Show the results on demand, using AJAX, which means:

- on page load show the list of Environments
- on Environment click (demand), send request to get Features
- on Feature click, ask for Days list

You could also combine those two methods.

Comment: So, would a simple JQuery `.load()` method work? But then what's an efficient way of retrieving the specific feature from the environment and then the days & reports?

Comment: Just think of it this way: One AJAX request for each of your dimensions. No need to request all the data, only the one visitors demands.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely going to want to pre-process that data in some way. You can either:

- Set up a recurring task (cron job?) to intake the data
- Set up a file system watcher to pick up changes to the files, and update your cache when they change

As for what you use to store that data, that mostly depends on how you intend to access it.  If you're simple pulling the entire collection down each time, it might be fine to just flatten it into a single file.  You could also look into something like using a MongoDB instance with a TTL index set to expire old records, or a memcache/redis server for very fast read times.